# como desenvolvo um sistema de cadastro, listagem e consulta de veículos e montadoras?obs:a listagem é por nome,por ano,faixa de preço e por motor

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-2.7

```
def main():
    titulo = '***** Veiculos.BD ***** \n '
    menu = titulo + '1 - Novo Veiculo \n 2 - Listar veiculos'\
    ' \n 3 - Remover \n 4 - editar \n 0 - Sair \n Opcao >> '


    veiculos = []

    while True:
        op = input(menu)

        if op == 1:
            veiculos.append(novo_veiculo())
            print'  VEiculo Cadastrado'
        elif op == 2:
            listar_veiculos(veiculos)
        elif op == 3:
            remover_veiculos(veiculos)
        elif op == 4:

        elif op == 0:
            break
        else:
            print 'opcao invalida'



def novo_veiculo():
    nome = raw_input('nome:  ')
    valor= input('valor: ')
    ano = input('ano: ')
    montadora = raw_input('montadora: ')
    pais = raw_input('pais de origem: ')
    veiculo = {'nome':nome, 'valor':valor, 'ano':ano ,'montadora' :montadora , 'pais' :pais}
    return veiculo


def listar_veiculos(veiculos):
    print '\nListar Veiculos\n'
    print 'nome \t valor \t ano \t montadora \t pais \t veiculo'
    for veiculo in veiculos:
        nome = veiculo['nome']
        valor= veiculo['valor']
        ano = veiculo['ano']
        montadora = veiculo['montadora']
        pais = veiculo['pais']
        print '%s \t %d \t %d \t %s \t %s' % (nome, valor, ano,montadora,pais)


def remover_veiculos(veiculos):
    listar_veiculos(veiculos)
    posicao = input('Qual indice? ')
    #del veiculos[posicao]
    removido = veiculos.pop(posicao)
    print 'veiculo: ', removido['nome'], ' removido.'


    titulo ='*****Montadora.BD***** \n'
    menu = titulo + ' 1 - Novo \n 2 - Listar'\
            ' \n 3 - Remover \n 0 - Sair \n OP >>  '

    while True:
        op = input(menu)

        if op == 1:
            veiculos.append(novo_veiculo())
            print'  Veiculo Cadastrado'
        elif op == 2:
            listar_veiculos(veiculos)
        elif op == 3:
            remover_veiculos(veiculos)

        elif op == 0:
            break
        else:
            print 'opcao invalida'






if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Seja bem-vinda, Jessica. Detalhe melhor a sua dúvida. Você já tem um código. Qual é o problema com ele? Se já não o fez, faça a nossa [tour] para entender melhor como fazer uma boa pergunta.